# How to get my function to be recursive? (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I'm having to make a recursive function that will receive a stack of "int" and output the sum of the squares of the elements in the stack.
Here is what I have

```
public int sum_sqr_rec(Stack<Integer> stk){
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<stk.size(); i++){
sum += (stk.get(i) * stk.get(i));
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: `if (stk.empty()) return 0; int i = stk.pop(); return i*i + sum_sqr_rec(stk);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing you need to determine for a recursive function is when to terminate it.

The second important thing to consider is what to return when you terminate it. When you start adding numbers, you start with `sum = 0`. From a recursive function, which is supposed to calculate the sum of numbers, the same value (i.e. `0`) can be returned when you terminate it. Similarly, from a recursive function, which is supposed to return the product of numbers, you can return `1` on termination.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.add(2);
        stack.add(3);
        stack.add(4);
        stack.add(5);
        System.out.println(sum_sqr_rec(stack));
    }

    static int sum_sqr_rec(Stack<Integer> stk) {
        if (stk.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        int n = stk.pop();
        return n * n + sum_sqr_rec(stk);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
54
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.add(2);
        stack.add(2);
        stack.add(4);
        stack.add(5);
        System.out.println(sum_sqr_rec(stack));
    }

    public static int sum_sqr_rec(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        return stack.peek() * stack.pop() + sum_sqr_rec(stack);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I use Deque interface rather than Stack class directly (documentation says it should be used in preference to the Stack class).

```
    public int recursive(Deque<Integer> stk){
        if (stk.Empty()){
            return 0;
        }
        return Math.pow(stack.pop(), 2) + recursive(stk);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.  But if you don't want to destroy the stack you can do it this way.  The stack is restored during the return process.

- `n` is popped.  This depletes the stack of numbers and keeps `n` in the local call stack for later use.
- The square of the element is saved on the call stack of the method in `k`
- `r` is initialized for the final tally.
- Once the stack is empty, simply push `n` back on `stk` and return the sums of the saved squares.

```
static int sum_sqr_rec(Stack<Integer> stk) {
      int n = stk.pop();
      int k = n*n;
      int r = 0;
      if (!stk.isEmpty()) {
            r = sum_sqr_rec(stk);
      }
      stk.push(n);
      return r + k;
}
```

Using this call sequence of statements.

```
System.out.println(stack);
System.out.println(sum_sqr_rec(stack));
System.out.println(stack);
```

Results in the following

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
54
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```